# Stop a Runnable in a Thread imediatly

Tags: java, multithreading, stm

I try to implement a version of software transactional memory library in java with some sort of scheduler which holds some Thread objects. I want to implement a mechanism where the scheduler tells the Thread to immediatly stop execution, drop its Runnable, create a new one and rerun it. This is really half cooked so far but what I don't want is to recreate the hole Thread because it will work as a state holder for several Variables (deepcopies of other variables only the Thread has - copy tasks are a choke here so the Thread should not be fully recreated)

My problem is that I don't know about anything that terminates a method while it executes and frees all the resources (If the scheduler tells the thread to restart everything the Runnable did is invalid and must be redone) and start the run method again with fresh input variables.

The goal is to avoid unecesarry executions and there should be no variable in the runnable which asks if it was interreupted to then skip the execution or something. Just stop the execution and kill it from something the runnable itself is not aware off. I hope it's clear what I want if not please ask for the unclear points help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: This is rather impossible. There must be some signal to the Thread telling it to stop (Why the interrupt mechanism is in place) otherwise it will keep on going until it finishes. You *could* use the deprecated method `Thread#stop` but that doesn't do *any* cleanup.

Comment: @Quirliom: I'm wondering if you can't kill the thread by performing OS calls. After all, the OS decides which threads have control over the CPU.

Comment: @CommuSoft Using Java? Unlikely.

Comment: @Quirliom: The old versions of java indeed had a virtual-machine defined approach, but later Java switched to POSIX threads. Mainly due to performance issues.

Comment: Use an ExecutorService and maintain a reference to the Future and use it's cancel method. Your runnable will need to monitor the interrupted state if the current thread

Comment: Also, it feels to me like Java's `synchronized` keyword already implements a "transaction" over one or more memory address.  Feels a bit like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Well in my testing it seems that Thread#stop is not always stopping the Thread directly. I could use wrapper for the Thread and hold the variable states in that wrapper instead of the Thread itself and then recreate the Thread this would solve it. But Thread#stop is deprecated and atleast leaves open files if I remember correctly.

Comment: The cleanup needed is rather small. Its a transaction based approach so everything that actually does unrerollable changes like file writing or something must not be in this threads. But the programmer should not be in charge of stopping and retrying a transaction he should only provide the method for transactional context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Tutorial to cancel the Runnable and start it again.

```
public class RestartThreadTutorial {
public static void main(String args[]){
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    Future<?> taskHandler = executorService.submit(new Task());
    //restart the task after 3 seconds.
    try{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        //empty
    }
    taskHandler.cancel(true); //it will cancel the running thread
    if (taskHandler.isCancelled()==true){//check the thread is cancelled
        executorService.submit(new Task());//then create new thread..
    }
}

public static class Task implements Runnable{
    private int secondsCounter;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Thread -"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"elapsed - "+ (secondsCounter++) +"second");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks like I have to look into Futures here.